# Update statements within if are getting executed even when condition is false

Tags: oracle, plsql

Issue with update statements in pl/sql block.
If table not exists, then it shouldn't execute update statements.

Update statements are appending 01 to startdate
and last day of month to end date.

```
SET SQLBLANKLINES ON;
   
    DECLARE
    v_table_exists varchar2(2);
    BEGIN
        SELECT count(*) INTO v_table_exists FROM USER_TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'PRICECHANGE_FULL';
        IF (v_table_exists = '1') THEN
            UPDATE PRICECHANGE_FULL SET PS_START_MONTH=TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(PS_START_MONTH, 'YYYYMM'), 'YYYYMMDD') WHERE LENGTH(PS_START_MONTH)=6;
            UPDATE PRICECHANGE_FULL SET VC_ITEM_START_MONTH=TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(VC_ITEM_START_MONTH, 'YYYYMM'), 'YYYYMMDD') WHERE LENGTH(VC_ITEM_START_MONTH)=6;
            UPDATE PRICECHANGE_FULL SET CALC_ITEM_START_MONTH=TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(CALC_ITEM_START_MONTH, 'YYYYMM'), 'YYYYMMDD') WHERE LENGTH(CALC_ITEM_START_MONTH)=6;
            UPDATE PRICECHANGE_FULL SET ITEM_START_MONTH=TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(ITEM_START_MONTH, 'YYYYMM'), 'YYYYMMDD') WHERE LENGTH(ITEM_START_MONTH)=6;
    
            UPDATE PRICECHANGE_FULL SET PS_EXPIRY_MONTH=TO_CHAR(LAST_DAY(TO_DATE(PS_EXPIRY_MONTH, 'YYYYMM')), 'YYYYMMDD') WHERE LENGTH(PS_EXPIRY_MONTH)=6;
            UPDATE PRICECHANGE_FULL SET ITEM_END_MONTH=TO_CHAR(LAST_DAY(TO_DATE(ITEM_END_MONTH, 'YYYYMM')), 'YYYYMMDD') WHERE LENGTH(ITEM_END_MONTH)=6;
            UPDATE PRICECHANGE_FULL SET VC_ITEM_END_MONTH=TO_CHAR(LAST_DAY(TO_DATE(VC_ITEM_END_MONTH, 'YYYYMM')), 'YYYYMMDD') WHERE LENGTH(VC_ITEM_END_MONTH)=6;
            UPDATE PRICECHANGE_FULL SET CALC_ITEM_END_MONTH=TO_CHAR(LAST_DAY(TO_DATE(CALC_ITEM_END_MONTH, 'YYYYMM')), 'YYYYMMDD') WHERE LENGTH(CALC_ITEM_END_MONTH)=6;
            COMMIT;
        END IF;
    END;
    /
    
    exit;
```

**Error**: If table doesn't exists, I'm getting table not found error (update statements shouldn't get executed in this case).

Comment: That code looks ok. It's unclear what you want help with. Are you getting an error ? Does it give you an unexpected result ?

Comment: @KoenLostrie added error in question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That code can't possibly work if table `pricechange_full` doesn't exist; it wouldn't compile. If you want to have such a code, you'll have to use **dynamic SQL**.

Apart from that:

- `count` function returns a NUMBER; why are you comparing it to a string? `v_table_exists = '1'` - should be `= 1`
- the whole idea here is to - as you said -

  > append 01 to startdate

  It means that you are storing dates as strings. (Again strings? Do you love them that much?) That's really a bad, Bad, BAD, **BAD** idea. Store dates into `DATE` datatype columns. Once you do that, you won't need such a code (you wrote & posted in the question) and everything will work by itself